# How to query SNMP to get OID and Date from IP

Tags: python, snmp, oid

Hello I have a project in python to try to learn more about things I will be learning later in college and I have written out the steps below. I know how to read out write to files and export as a csv from a list but running the SNMP query and getting the OID is my problem. I am sorry if this is a stupid question or the answer is easily accessible.

1. Read in a list of IP addresses from a text file
2. Run an SNMP query against each ip address
3. Looking for the value of a specific OID (1.3.6.1.4.1.318.1.1.1.2.2.4.0). That OID is a string value (a date, more specifically)
4. Write the ip address and the date returned by the query to a different text file (csv format, preferably)

Answer (score 0):

There are several libraries in Python for performing SNMP queries, but here's one example of how you would perform a query using the `snmp` library (`pip install snmp`)

```
from snmp.engine import Engine
from snmp.message import MessageProcessingModel
from snmp.types import OctetString

addrs = [] # populate with your addresses

with Engine() as engine:
    for addr in addrs:
        manager = engine.Manager(addr, version=MessageProcessingModel.SNMPv2c, community=b"public")
        response = manager.get("1.3.6.1.4.1.318.1.1.1.2.2.4.0")
        value = response.variableBindings[0].value

        if isinstance(value, OctetString):
            print(value.data)
        else:
            print(f"Unexpected result: {value}")
```